# Click on multiple links using WDIO, Node, Selenium

Tags: html, node.js, selenium, testing, mocha.js

I'm currently trying to write a web testing script which clicks all the links within my side bar. The problem is the amount of links changes depending on what the user has access to/has turned on.

My side bar is called `$('#side-menu-bar')` and the `li's` inside of it have class `$('.side-menu-item')`.

According to WDIO's API, I should be able to do:

```
it('should fetch menu links and visit each page', function () {
    links = $$('#side-menu-bar li a');

    links.forEach(function (link) {
       link.click();
    });
});
```

When run - this will click the **first** link as many times are there are `li's` in the `$('#side-menu-bar')`.

I've read and applied lots of previous discussions and answers to questions similar to this, however none have worked. Is this do-able/easier with perhaps a different framework? Currently using Mocha with a standalone-selenium server.